# is there a way for me to fix '0 rows affected' in my multi table delete statement?

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue with my mysql query that should remove all occurrences of a specific ID (this ID is a foreign key in the other tables)

> DELETE FROM animals, foodforanimal, notes, staffforanimal USING
> animals INNER JOIN foodforanimal INNER JOIN notes INNER JOIN
> staffforanimal
> WHERE animals.ID = foodforanimal.AnimalID
> AND foodforanimal.AnimalID = notes.AnimalID
> AND notes.AnimalID = staffforanimal.AnimalID
> AND animals.ID = 2

It runs without any errors being picked up by sqlyog but isn't changing the database and says '0 rows affected'. Any help/advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: there seems to be a missing space in `notes.AnimalIDAND` and in `staffforanimal.AnimalIDAND`, so i doube that  "It runs without any errors"  (Please try to format your query, so it will be show on multiple lines, and readable without using the horizontal scroll bar....)

Comment: @Luuk the missing spaces was me trying to use stack overflow as I'm not used to the system, not my code as it is spaced on different lines in sqlyog. By 'runs without any errors' I meant errors that would be picked up by sql. any thoughts?

Comment: I am referring to the statement you provide on SO, I cannot see the statements in your sqlyog, or any other logs you use....

Comment: @Luuk  DELETE FROM animals, foodforanimal, notes, staffforanimal USING animals INNER JOIN foodforanimal INNER JOIN notes INNER JOIN staffforanimal
WHERE animals.ID = foodforanimal.AnimalID 
AND foodforanimal.AnimalID = notes.AnimalID 
AND notes.AnimalID = staffforanimal.AnimalID 
AND animals.ID = 11;

Comment: does this help?

Comment: no, you should use [edit] to change the question... 

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the old join syntax and don't mix it with the new one. Use proper joins like this:

```
DELETE a, f, n, s
FROM animals a
INNER JOIN foodforanimal f ON a.ID = f.AnimalID
INNER JOIN notes n ON f.AnimalID = n.AnimalID
INNER JOIN staffforanimal s ON n.AnimalID = s.AnimalID
WHERE a.ID = 11
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @NicoHaase thank you for the advice, however it is still saying 0 rows affected.

Comment: @user17410644:: Then the problem is not the query.